# My KeyspaceEventMessageListener doHandleMessage doesn't get called when I run springboot app using nohup

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-redis

I have written a Springboot application `implementing CommandLineRunner`. In that, I have written my custom listener class `ListOpsPushEventMessageListener extends KeyspaceEventMessageListener` and registered it to listen to topics `PatternTopic("__keyevent@*:*push")`. When I run this app in shell using `java -jar <My app jar>` the listener's `protected void doHandleMessage(Message message)` gets called whenever list pushes happen in redis.

However, when I try to run the same as a background job using nohup java -jar  &, the listener's doHandleMessage is not getting called at all.

Any idea why this is happening? and how can we resolve this problem so that I can run my app using nohup?